# Visual Studio 2019 gives error trying to load folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I've had this problem for a while now, and googling gives me literally zero results.

So, using Visual Studio 2019, if I try to open a folder (any folder), I always get the same error message:

```
"This part: (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.Remote.SolutionView.FolderCustomView) cannot be instantiated."
```

So far I've tried repairing my VS 2019 installation (which didn't work), then deleted the following folders:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon
```

Which also didn't work...Opening the same folder in VS 2017 works fine, but I'm at a loss as to why 2019 behaves like this, and a google of `"FolderCustomView"` (in quotes) returns zero results...Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a conflict in the view with different versions installed, i suggest you to remove the 2017 and go with 2019.

If the problem still exists - is this happening across all the folders you are trying to open or only a specific one?